# Why "hyperledger-fabric" private data collections cannot query the PDC and make changes to it on the same transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**NOTE:** I'm trying to use `PrivateDataCollections` on `hyperledger` fabric 1.2

We are migrating code to use `PDC` that was writing to the ledger before, and we were executing range queries and changing state on the same transaction on ledger.

What we do is run some kind of range query first to get a list of all the related objects load them and change state, this was working fine so far.

With `PDC` we kept the same approach but now we are getting an error when we 
try to put data on `PDC`. This is the error message we are getting.

> Transaction has already performed queries on pvt data. Writes are not
>   allowed

We're using this combination without any problems:

```
GetStateByPartialCompositeKey
PutState
```

But this is not working;

```
GetPrivateDataByPartialCompositeKey
PutPrivateData
```

Is this by design or is there an option to override this behaviour?

I do not see any problems with writing to `SideDB` even when you query it, what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I found this on HLF boards. https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5096?focusedCommentId=45327&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-45327  so my understanding is that; range queries are going to cause problems on peers that are not part of the PDC, so the transaction could not be committed in any ways.

Answer (score 1):

In my function i am using

```
GetPrivateDataByPartialCompositeKey  
PutState
```

Still it is complaining

> Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500
> message:"error in simulation: transaction returned with failure:
> Error: PUT_STATE failed:
> Transaction has already performed queries on pvt data. Writes are not
> allowed"